# Django constant argument on URL

Tags: django, url, django-templates

I have an URL on django with this pattern in my urls.py

```
    url(r'^client/(?P<email>[^/]+)/events/(?P<count>[^/]+)/$', login_required(list_events_from_client), name='events_from_client'),
```

As you can see, the url is formatted with first a constant, variable email, constant, and then variable count.

The problem is that I have no idea how to generate this url on the template using the tag url. If the url didn't have the second constant (events), I could simply do it like:

```
{% url 'admin:client' email.value count.value  %}
```

But I don't know how to put this second constant.

Comment: That URL tag should work, what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `{% url %}` tag you should pass the values for regex groups (the expressions in the round brackets) only so this will work just fine:

```
{% url 'events_from_client' email.value count.value %}
```

Comment: Should note that this works (and is the right solution) because you're using the `name` of the url.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't notice I was actually using the name of the url, I always had the same value for the name and for the pattern, so I though was using the pattern. This worked for me. I cant select the answer as correct now, but I will do it when I can. Thanks